# PFImage in table view too large

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, tableview

I'm using Parse. I have a column in my table to store images as PFFiles. I am using a PFQueryTableViewController. I want to display images in my Parse table's "image" column as thumbnails for each table view cell that has an image associated with it.

Here is the relevant `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code I'm suspicious of:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell! {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ListingCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as PFTableViewCell

    // This works as you can see "grapes" displayed on the screenshot I added.
    var label = cell.viewWithTag(2) as UILabel
    label.text = object["title"] as? String

    // Accessing the PFImageView within my custom PFTableViewCell via a tag
    let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(3) as PFImageView

    // Extracting the image stored as a PFFile stored in the database
    imageView.file = object["image"] as? PFFile // remote image

    // Setting the actual thumbnail with the image when loaded 
    imageView.loadInBackground { (image: UIImage!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        imageView.image = image
    }

    return cell
}
```

I have 2 records stored in this Parse table, the first does not have an image and the second one does (hence why the "grapes" cell is empty). My question is, why is the image not displaying in the thumbnail (properly constrained) I created and rather taking up the entire screen? What am I doing wrong here? The even weirder part is that I used Xcode's view debugging to capture the view hierarchy and it shows it properly placed within the thumbnail. Any ideas?

[image: screenshot of PFQueryTableView]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your image mode is set to something like "Scale To Fill".